# javafx adding button to panel

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

My panel `@FXML Panel mpanel;` i want to add button in mpanel

```
Button  temp = new Button("Button " + i);
                    temp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("button"+y1);
                        }
                    });
            mpanel.add(temp);
```

I am getting syntax error on line `mpanel.add(temp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2011/06/02/using-javafx-20-inside-swing-applications it looks like you can add it to Swing with a JFXPanel, not sure about awt.

Comment: i want to add button in panel

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Panel class in javafx, only in java.awt. If there is a Panel class in yout javafx, then use mpanel.getChildren().add(temp);. But if it's in the swing (not sure if it works in awt) use a jfxpanel and read the article I linked.